# Reliable network data usage by process?

Tags: networking, internet

I can only use up to 5GB/month and my provider claims that I used 500MB since my contract started yesterday. But I haven't watched a single video and everything looks just right (I'm currently using Process Explorer to find out which process sends/receives how much data).
So is it possible that Process Explorer is missing something? Maybe Windows Updates or so? Is there an alternative that allows be to see how many bytes each process is sending/receiving on my network?

Note: My PC is the only device in my network, I have no Wifi and doubt that I have any viruses on my PC.

Answer (score 0):

[Glasswire Free](https://www.glasswire.com/download/) can show you usage by application and by site (so you can determine if you need to block a particular high-connectivity site).

[image: Glasswire showing usage]

For other such tools, see [Alternatives To (Glasswire)](http://alternativeto.net/software/glasswire/).